# Setting Session Variables and Calling them on Another Page

Tags: php, arrays, session, authentication

I salute you all for your previous help.
Would anyone imagine this very simple error, which has put me down for a couple of hours.

From the Login Page, I compare (authenticate) the login username and password with the database values. If they match, I store them in session variables and redirect to the dashboard page.

Before redirection, I print_r ($_SESSION) to see whether the variables are set or not. They output was TRUE (session is set).

But on the dashboard, calling the session variables returned session !set.
Please check the following code.

[LOGIN PAGE]

```
<?php

session_start();

require_once('../data/conString_mysqli.php');
$uNameErr = $pWordErr = "";
$uName = $pWord = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

   //*************************************
    if (!empty($_POST["username"])) {
        $uName = test_input($_POST["username"]);
    } else {
        $uNameErr = "Email is required!";
        // check if e-mail address is well-formed
        if (!filter_var($uName, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            $uNameErr = "Invalid email format"; 
        }
    }
    if (!empty($_POST["password"])) {
        $pWord = test_input($_POST["password"]);
        $hashed = md5($pWord);
    } else {
        $pWord1Err = "Password is Required!";
        if ($pWord < 8) {
            $pWordErr = "Invalid Password.";
        }
    }

}//end if... IS_POST
    function test_input($data) {
    //require connection file

        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);    
        return $data;
    }//end function
?>

<?php

    if (!empty($uName) && !empty($pWord)){
        $hashed = md5($pWord);

        $read_data = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM service_providers WHERE activated='1' AND ppword ='".$hashed."' AND pemail='".$uName."'") or die(mysqli_error());

        $count = mysqli_num_rows($read_data);
        if($count >= 1){/*echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Records Found!");</script>';*/

            //store session variables
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($read_data);
            $_SESSION[ 'serv_pid' ]     = $row[ 'serv_pid' ];
            $_SESSION[ 'providerName' ] = $row[ 'pname' ];

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Session Name: '.$_SESSION['providerName']." - Session ID: ". $_SESSION['serv_pid'].'");window.location="../dashboard/";</script>'; 

/*echo "<pre>";
print_r ($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
*/      
        }else{echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("Invalid Login Details");window.location="../login/";</script>';

        }
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" style="margin-top: 1.5em;">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="username (your email)" value="<?php echo $uName;?>"><span class="error"> <?php echo $uNameErr;?></span>
<span class="input-group-addon btn btn-warning" style="background: #f0ad4e; color: #fff;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" style="margin: 0;"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="input-group">
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control text-center" placeholder="password" value="<?php echo $pWord;?>"><span class="error"> <?php echo $pWordErr;?></span>
<span class="input-group-addon btn btn-warning" style="background: #f0ad4e; color: #fff;">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock" style="margin: 0;"></span>
</span>
</div>
</div>

<p style="font-size: 16px !important;"><a style="color: #fff; text-decoration: none; margin-top: 2em; display: block;" href="../sign-up/">Don't have an Account? <u>Get one!</u></a> <span style="color:#FF0000; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:underline;"><em><a href="forgot_pass.php" title="Click here to get your password">Forgot your password?</a></em></span></p>
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 text-center" style="margin-top: 5px;">
<button type="submit" name="login" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg btn-custom" style="margin-right: 1em; border-width: 3px;">LOGIN</button>
<a href="../sign-up/" class="btn btn-warning" style="background: none !important; border: 3px solid #fff;">SIGN UP</a>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

[DASHBOARD PAGE]

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<pre>";
print_r ($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";


/*
if (!isset($_SESSION['serv_pid'])){// or !isset($_SESSION['providerName'])){
    die('<script type="text/javascript">alert("You do not have permission to access beyond the previous page.");window.location="../login/";</script>');
}else{
    $serv_pid = $_SESSION['serv_pid'];
    $pName = $_SESSION['providerName'];
}*/
?>
```

From the Login Page, the result returned by print_r is:

Array
(
    [serv_pid] => 1
    [providerName] => No Name
)

But on getting to the login page, it's like the session is destroyed.
The result returned by print_r is:

Array
(
)

Please help me with any ideas.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're setting the session once the user logs in and then redirecting him to the dashboard. Right? So, why would he again come to the login page if he's already logged in? He would be able to come back to the login page only if he's logged out i.e session is destroyed. Not sure where exactly you're facing the issue.

Comment: On the dashboard page, the server checks whether there is a session created for that user. If FALSE, the user goes back to the login page. The issue is; on the dashboard page, the server does not even find a session. Meanwhile, there was a session. It's like the session gets destroyed after the login page. How can you maintain a session until it is codingly destroyed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you start a session in PHP, it sets a session cookie, that's sent to the browser when you print the first character outside `php` brackets or at your first `echo`.
I think the problem is when you try to redirect the user to the dashboard page. You're setting the session, writing to the browser a script that redirects to another page, but in the meanwhile the server doesn't stop the processing on the page.

Try replacing the `echo "<script>..."` with a `header("Location: dashboard.php")` in PHP, followed by a `exit(0);` instruction.
The first one actually tells the browser to redirect to the dashboard.php page (or whatever the page is), the second tells the browser to stop executing the page.

Moreover, delete the blank row between `?>` and `<?php` brackets. That row actually sends the headers to the browser, along with cookies, even if it's a blank character.

Comment: Thanks for your correction. But for the <script> redirection, I prefer to use that instead of header, because header does not allow you to check error messages before the redirection. Usually, I use alert() in the <script> tag to check for errors or successes. I've actually created 2 fresh pages to check the session from scratch and they worked. Going back to my codes, I notice that, there is a session start on the header.php and the body.php pages. So, I need to drop the entire pages and recreate them one line at a time to check where there is a replicate session_start() event.

Comment: In my opinion, you should redirect only if login is successful. Otherwise, you should print the login form, without redirecting, along with the error messages, like alerts. Well, my advice is to put the header instruction only on successful login. If you really need the alert, you can always put it on the dashboard page, so you'll see it after the redirect; that's not so bad, since the user won't see the real difference ;).

Comment: Yeah, I get what you're saying. Thanks. Meanwhile, like I said before, I have checked through the pages one line at a time, and I removed excess session_start(). It's working perfectly now. I will be uploading the site now. You can check it on servicehub.ng/home/

Comment: That's a bit strange. Calling session_start twice actually doesn't open two different sessions: http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: It does not but rather, cancels the other and destroys the variables. It's strange though. By the way, have you checked the site? www.servicehub.ng/home/

Comment: I gave a look, but I can't solve your php script problems from my browser, of course ;) debug your code. You could encounter bigger problems with sessions in future, while developing the code for your site. In my opinion, calling session_start only once is just a workaround for your case. In my experience, I've never had problems in calling it at every page of my sites ;)

Comment: The thing is that, in the index.php page, I call the header.php and the footer.php likewise. So, there are session_start() on the header.php and the index.php as well as other pages. This poses the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There were excess session_start() functions on the landing page and on the sending page. Each session_start() cancelled the other and the variables were destroyed before getting to the landing page.

However, I had to drop the entire pages and recreate them one line at a time. So, it's working now.

I really want to appreciate Marco Todisco, who also contributed suggestive responses to assisting me on my coding.